# Concentrated into, or condensed into?

Tags: word-choice

> This is a book concentrated into one chapter. It is very dense.

I heard it from a Cambridge professor. He was praising a chapter well written about an ancient philosopher by a famous scholar, which was collected in a book editted by himself.

But I think a book which is concentrated into one chapter is still a complete book. It is simply written in an extremely dense style.

Maybe the professor shoulds say "a book condensed into one chapter". Because a book which has been condensed into one chapter is just a book which originally had more than one chapter and has been reduced to its essentials and stuffed into one chapter.

Answer (score 1):

***Condensed*** is undoubtedly the better option to use. It's perfect for your context.

***Concentration***, in the simplest of words, is the *amount of a constituent* amongst a mixture of things. A concentrated solution has more amount of solute inside the solvent.

It doesn't really make sense when you apply it to the context. He could probably correctly say that he *concentrated the information in the book* (which would mean the amount of useful information was kept, removing the unuseful stuff), but concentrating it *into a chapter* doesn't seem to fit the verb.

Comment: 'Concentration' does make sense if the chapter was not actually a condensation of the book--if the professor was speaking metaphorically: some chapters of philosophy are so complex and subtle that they could be expanded into a book, and this is one such chapter.   Absent other context (e.g., the knowledge of a source book), this interpretation is quite possible.  Besides, philosophers tend not to abridge their own works--I'm speaking from experience!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your professor was saying,

> "This book contains the equivalent of numerous ordinary chapters, but in the space of one extraordinarily dense chapter."

If virtually anyone were to hear his words in the context of an extemporaneous lecture which was not read word for word, I imagine he or she would get the gist of the professor's words.

With the luxury of hindsight, it's easy for us to unpack and re-phrase his words with more accuracy than can be expected from a lecturer who may have used only an outline as the basis for his or her lecture.

As for concentrated or condensed, that depends.  It it's all good stuff, with very little--if any--fluff, then it's concentrated.  If the fluff has been removed so that only the good and necessary stuff remains, then it's condensed.  Either way, my version is more accurate, I think, and it needs neither *condensed* nor *concentrated*.

I am, however, left with a nagging question:  Does the book in question eschew chapter numbers in favor of one continuous string of prose?